# Azure Active Directory group changes synchronization

Tags: azure, authorization, azure-active-directory

We are adding an Azure AD application (say App1) to an AD group (say Group1) and using this for authorization. But sometimes the authorization is failing as Azure is taking some time for replicating this change (may be 5-10 seconds).

Is there any way we can make sure the permissions are reflected in Azure AD across tenants?

Is there an API through which we can force this synchronization?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say you're adding an app to a group? Are you referring to assigning a group to an application (e.g. in the Azure management portal, under the app's configuration?)?

Comment: We are adding app to groups through the APIs as shown below:

adGroup.Members.Add(adApp);
await adGroup.UpdateAsync();

Comment: I see. And is `adApp` a ServicePrincipal or an Application? I'm curious -- what scenario calls for immediate authorization instants after making group membership changes?

Answer (score 0):

There's no method to force this, and 5-10 seconds sounds about normal for replication delays inside Azure AD to take place.

Your best bet is to add a delay before you attempt to do authorization that depends on the newly-changed group membership, and include some retry logic with (possibly exponential) back-off.